# Program received signal:"SIGABRT"

Tags: objective-c

i'm beginning to code with the objective-c,by using xcode 4.2.1...I'm following a tutorial online but i have a problem...
The code is this:

```
-(IBAction)sum{
int x = [[first text] intValue];
int y = [[second text] intValue];
int t = x + y;

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",t];
[ris setText:result];
```

}

When i click on start debug,the ios simulator opens and appears the error:
Program received signal:"SIGABRT"

Thanks to who will help me!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create ".gdbinit" file in your home directory

```
$ ~/
```

in the .gdbinit file put some future breakpoints, I suggest to start off with these:

```
fb objc_exception_throw
fb malloc_error_break
fb _NSLockError
fb NSKVODeallocateBreak
fb _NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler
fb malloc_printf
fb _NSAutoreleaseNoPool
fb CGErrorBreakpoint
```

This will help you to find where the SIGABRT is originating in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

One of the variables `first`, `second` or `ris` is pointing to a deallocated object.